# Watin- cant select an item from a selectlist dropdown using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox, drop-down-menu, watin, selectlist

net/watin application and I am trying to select and item from a combobox on a client's website. I can use watin to drop the list down and select (highlite) an item from the list but the selected item will not populate the textbox above. It seems like watin's .select() is not triggering an event to fire.

I can work around this by writing in the first letter of the item in the combobox and use the hypertext feature to select the item but this is not ideal.

Can someone please point out why the following code wont populate the combobox?
Thanks

Here is the code that should select a combobox item:

```
    '***Find combobox frame
    Dim ie_tabWell1 As Frame
    ie_tabWell1 = ie.Frame(Find.ById("sframeInner")).Frame(Find.ById("wellFrame")).Frame(Find.ById("tabWell1"))


    '*** Drop down the list (Not really needed)
    ie_tabWell1.TextField(Find.ById("ctlMaritalStatusText__")).ClickNoWait()
    'ie_tabWell1.Span(Find.ByValue("Single")).Focus()

    '*** Select the list item (Selects an item but dosn't populate the combobox)
    ie_tabWell1.SelectList(Find.ById("ctlMaritalStatusList__")).Option(Find.ByText("Single")).Select()        
    ie_tabWell1.TextField(Find.ById("ctlMaritalStatusText__")).Refresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is being caused by how the application is triggering the population of the list, i.e. they are triggering of an event that WatiN is not firing when clicking on the item.

We had a similar problem and we needed to find the item, then focus on it, and then click with a mouse click to fire the event properly.

Another way would have been to call the document.eval method to fire the javascript event myself, however that is starting to screw around with the application being tested a bit too much IMHO.

Comment: A late thanks. I was able to use object.keypress(character) to force the dropdown to react to react like data is comming from the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I had the my code quite similar to yours and having the same problem

ie.SelectList("drpmcCreateVisitTypeSelect").Option("CARDIOLOGY CONSULTATION").Select();

But after adding this to my snippet, I got the expected behaviour, we need to fire the Click() event to get the item selected as

ie.SelectList("drpmcCreateVisitTypeSelect").Option("CARDIOLOGY CONSULTATION").Click();